# No consigo insertar datos en Access desde C#

Tags: c#

No sé dónde está el problema, no me da ningún tipo de excepción, simplemente se ejecuta y sigue, pero no inserta los datos en Access.

```
    static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source="+AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"Leaderboard.accdb");
    static OleDbCommand comando;
    
    public static void highscore(int puntuacion, String nombre)
    {
        try { 
        String query;
        con.Open();

        query = "Insert into Leaderboard(Nick,Puntuacion) Values('"+nombre+"','"+puntuacion+"')";

        comando.CommandText = query;
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Auxiliar.log(e.Message);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me faltaba el proveedor de OLEDB para insertar datos en acces.

El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no está registrado en el equipo local.
Dejo el link por si alguien tiene el mismo problema o algo.

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734